# New to coding python , need help on why my code isnt working?

Tags: python

```
def Factorial(n):
    num = 1
    while n >= 1:
        num = num * n
        n = n - 1
    return num

def Fibonacci(num):
    i=0
    present=1
    previous=0
    while i<=num:
    nextterm=present+previous
    present=previous
    previous=nextterm
    i=i+1
    print("The fibonacci number for", i, 'is', nextterm)

def CallFibOrFac(x):
    num = 10
    if x == 'Fib':
        Fibonacci(num)
    if x == 'Fac':
        print (Factorial(n))

x = input('enter fibonacci or factorial')
num = input('enter value for fibonacci')
Fibonacci(num)
n = input('enter value for factorial'
print(Factorial(n))
```

I defined all my functions and wrote an `if` statement, but when I enter `Factorial`, when it asks for x=input(‘enter fibonacci or factorial’), it gives me the input to ‘enter value for fibonacci’ when I need the `n=input(‘enter value for factorial’)` to display when I put in "factorial".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a function to choose whether to call Fib or Fact, you never call that deciding function.  Instead, what I take to be your main program utterly ignores the user's first input and proceeds to call both functions.

Back up a few steps.  Learn to recognize the user's input and call -- or do *not* call -- a single function.